# How to get all the folderIDs of its parent folders?

Tags: box

In box application, I am in /a/b/c/construction. I have folder ID of construction. How to get all the folder IDs of its parent folders i.e, to get the folder IDs of c,b,a folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent folder ID of a folder using the [Get Folder's Info endpoint](https://docs.box.com/reference#get-folder-info). Here is a cURL example.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```